# WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: texSubImage2D: no bound PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER

Tags: webgl, webgl2

### Update:

For WebGL2 call declartions see the end of this post please

### Problem Description

I get this error when making a call to my function to load data into texture. I am using Chrome 68 browser. The code works in `WebGL1` but not in `WebGL2`.
My parameters for WebGL (internalFormat, format, channelType) are as below:

### WebGL 1:

```
  internalFormat: number = WebGLRenderingContext.RGBA;
  format: number = WebGLRenderingContext.RGBA;
  channelType: number = WebGLRenderingContext.FLOAT;
  channelSize = 4;
```

### WebGL 2:

```
  internalFormat: number = WebGL2RenderingContext.R32F;
  format: number = WebGL2RenderingContext.RED;
  channelType: number = WebGLRenderingContext.FLOAT;
  channelSize = 1;
```

In WebGL 1 and 2 I enable this extension:

```
this.textureFloatExtension = this.gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
```

In WebGL 2 I enable this additionally:

```
this.colorBufferFloatExtension = this.gl.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float');
```

And the function definitions:

```
updateTexture(texture: WebGLTexture, width: number, height: number, data: Float32Array): void {
    const gl = this.gl;
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    let buffer: ValidArrayTypes = data;
    if (data) {
      buffer = this.encoder.encode(data, width * height);
    }
    gl.texSubImage2D(
        gl.TEXTURE_2D,
        0,  // level
        0,  // xoffset
        0,  // yoffset
        width, height, this.encoder.format, this.encoder.channelType, buffer);
    this.checkError();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
  }
```

The texture is created prior to this call using the following:

```
allocateTexture(width: number, height: number): WebGLTexture {
    const gl = this.gl;

    // Create the texture
    const texture = gl.createTexture();
    // Bind the texture so the following methods effect this texture.
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    gl.texImage2D(
        gl.TEXTURE_2D,
        0,  // Level of detail.
        this.encoder.internalFormat, width, height,
        0,  // Always 0 in OpenGL ES.
        this.encoder.format, this.encoder.channelType, null);
    this.checkError();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    return texture as WebGLTexture;
  }
```

### API Declarations (WebGL2):

```
texSubImage2D(target: number, level: number, xoffset: number, yoffset: number,
        width: number, height: number,
        format: number, type: number, pixels?: ArrayBufferView | null): void;
    texSubImage2D(target: number, level: number, xoffset: number, yoffset: number,
        format: number, type: number, source: ImageData | HTMLImageElement | HTMLCanvasElement | HTMLVideoElement): void; // May throw DOMException
    texSubImage2D(target: number, level: number, xoffset: number, yoffset: number,
        format: number, type: number, source: ImageBitmap | ImageData | HTMLImageElement | HTMLCanvasElement | HTMLVideoElement): void; // May throw DOMException
```

Comment: This error appears if you use the version of `texSubImage2D` with an offset instead of a bufferview. What is the type of your `buffer` at the moment of the call?

Comment: In WebGL2, the format is gl.RED and channelType is gl.FLOAT. The buffer is just a Float32Array . The encoder here does nothing. It just passed back the original data. However in WebGL1 the encoder would blow up the data by a factor of 4 because of RGBA floats.

Comment: Try passing 0 as an extra argument, maybe it is required in WebGL2 (WebGL1 should safely ignore it).

Comment: These are the api declarations from @types/webgl2. There's only one call that can take 7 parameters and that's the one I'm calling with the width and height. There is no 8th parameter:
(please see edited post for the declarations)

Comment: Like @riv mentioned double check `buffer`. It might not be what you think it is.

Comment: Dunno where you're getting 7 parameters, on MDN there is a version with 10 parameters (the last one): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texSubImage2D

Comment: Same is in types/webgl2, a little further down.

Comment: @riv and gman: thank you very much. I stepped through the code and the buffer seemed not to be of the expected Float32Array. After correcting that everything runs fine. Very happy now :)

Comment: @riv. correct about the API as well. I didn't look hard enough after the first encounter